# How to add data from 2 queries into 1 table in webi

Tags: business-objects, webi

I have 2 queries.

The first query is from the webi universe which has:

```
Staff ID
Arrival Date
Leave Date
```

The 2nd query is an Excel data query that has:

```
Staff ID
Test Date
```

What I am want to do is to create a single table that has:

```
Staff ID 
Arrival Date 
Leave Date 
Test Date
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Create two data providers. First Data Provider using Universe will select Staff ID, Arrival Date, Leave Date. Second Data Provider using Excel Data Source will select Staff ID, Test Date. Run the queries. Once the data is fetched. Merge the common column (Staff ID). Then create a new table and drag the columns as required.